# Looking for highlight search where it will return all matching fields from one record

Tags: java, elasticsearch, vert.x

In highlighting search for my application how search works for us is if we pass pageSize it will only return one matching field from record.
For example
There are 4 records

remaining information added in comments as I am unable add code here please advice how can I achieve this requirement

Comment: [
   {
      "name":”jhon",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"willam",
      "firstname":"henry"
   },
   {
      "name":”kellin",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"kevin",
      "firstname":"mathew"
   },
   {
      "name":”keeper",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"Jr",
      "firstname":"gomez"
   },
   {
      "name":”Asif",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"peter",
      "firstname":"willaim kemp"
   }
]

Comment: user searching with "ke"

result will be like 
{
   "results": [
      {
         "fieldId": "name",
         "matchingText": "Kellin"
      },
      {
         "fieldId": "name",
         "matchingText": "keeper"
      },
      {
         "fieldId": "name",
         "matchingText": "willaim kemp"
      }
   ],
   "total_count": 4, //total number of records matching in es index
   "page": 1, 
   "pageSize": 3  //total no records per page
}

Comment: As u observed it is returning the only one matching fields per record it is ignoring if other fields matching also it is returning one per record. so what I understood is that it is returning one matching attribute for per record, it is ignoring other fields,

Comment: this is happening only for highlight search regular search is fine how can I implement to get result of all matching fields like one record 5 matching fields it should return all 5 and then after next record matching fields. how can we get total count should be total number of matching fields through out index and page size to be total number of matching fields for page

Answer (score 0):

If you need to [highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) the result of all matching fields of each document, then you can achieve this in the following way:

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "firstname": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "jhon",
  "Age": 24,
  "lastname": "willam",
  "firstname": "henry"
}
{
  "name": "kellin",
  "Age": 24,
  "lastname": "kevin",
  "firstname": "mathew"
}
{
  "name": "keeper",
  "Age": 24,
  "lastname": "Jr",
  "firstname": "gomez"
}
{
  "name": "Asif",
  "Age": 24,
  "lastname": "peter",
  "firstname": "willaim kemp"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "ke"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 20,
        "pre_tags": "<span class='bold'>",
        "post_tags": "</span>",
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64996939",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.1374959,
        "_source": {
          "name": "kellin",
          "Age": 24,
          "lastname": "kevin",
          "firstname": "mathew"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name": [
            "<span class='bold'>ke</span>llin"
          ],                                            <-- note this
          "lastname": [
            "<span class='bold'>ke</span>vin"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64996939",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.9552834,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Asif",
          "Age": 24,
          "lastname": "peter",
          "firstname": "willaim kemp"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "firstname": [
            "willaim <span class='bold'>ke</span>mp"      <-- note this
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64996939",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.62883455,
        "_source": {
          "name": "keeper",
          "Age": 24,
          "lastname": "Jr",
          "firstname": "gomez"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name": [
            "<span class='bold'>ke</span>eper"          <--note this
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I am able to get this but if I apply pagination I have a issue when I give page size value it is giving one match per record if give page size

Comment: @harishkumar thanks for your reply :) Are you applying pagination by using `size` param ?

Comment: Yes I am following pageNumber: 1 pageSize:3 like this

Comment: { "results": [ { "fieldId": "name", "matchingText": "Kellin" }, { "fieldId": "name", "matchingText": "keeper" }, { "fieldId": "name", "matchingText": "willaim kemp" } ], "total_count": 4, //total number of records matching in es index "page": 1, "pageSize": 3 //total no records per page } I am getting result like this even it is matching 4 fields but it is returning 3 in pageSize section and  3 in total_count section where I understood it is only returning one matching fields per record even it has two matching fields in one record when I apply pagination.